# Fake a real call on Android

Tags: android

Is there any chance to fake a call on Android?
I want it to ring and behave like there´s a real call (without the need of a second phone).

I searched the whole web. In the emulator I would telnet it and type "gsm call 12345", but I don´t know how to do it on a real device (rooted).

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: is this a fake call app?

Comment: no, i need to test my app SayMyName without the need of a second phone.

Comment: Ummmm...can't you just call it from a regular old phone? Surely, between multiple traditional carriers, multiple VOIP options, and multiple locations (e.g., home, office), there's gotta be *some* phone you can use or obtain inexpensively. Or, pick up a prepaid TracFone or something for cheap at a convenience store.

Comment: That´s exactly what I did till now. But it´s very annoying.

Something like telnet -> gms call 12345 on the phone would be perfect. But I don´t know how to do that on a real device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have one emulator dial another emulator.  Each emulator gets a number, like 5556, when it's run.  It's in the title bar of the emulator window, and that number is the phone number of that emulator, usable from within any other emulator.

Comment: thanks, but I want to call a real physical device. In my emulator everything works fine, but it doesn´t run correctly on my phone :(
It´s very annoying to ask friends to call you :/

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is [DeviceAnywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/)

Comment: What about abusing some click-to-call thing, like in Google Voice when it calls you to re-record a voicemail message?

Comment: Google Voice isn´t available in my country (Austria) :/